# Creating a folder in TFS using scripts

Tags: visual-studio-2010, version-control, tfs, tfsbuild

is it possible to create a folder in Source Controller Explorer using scripts?

I need to move the updated files to a folder.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create a script using the [TF.exe command line](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z51z7zy0%28v=vs.100%29) or using PowerShell (there are Cmdlets that can be installed with the [TFS Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f/)). If you want to create a folder, check out the *Add* command.  If you want to move files around, then check out the *Rename* command.